# Execute query before sending message

Tags: mysql, node.js, webhooks, facebook-messenger

I'm making a Messenger bot in NodeJS. I want users be able to request all their  trains. The problem is that we want to execute a query before NodeJS sends a message to the user.

I searched for asynchronous functions

```
function handlePostback(sender_psid, received_postback) {
let response;

// Get the payload for the postback
let payload = received_postback.payload;

// Set the response based on the postback payload
switch(payload){
    case "yes" : 
    let data = null
    axios.get('http://api.irail.be/connections/?from=Mechelen&to=Puurs&date=010219&time=1650&timesel=departure&format=json&lang=en&fast=false&typeOfTransport=trains&alerts=false&resul1=1')
    .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    data = data.response;
 })
response = {
        "text": data.connections.arrival.name
    }
   break;
 }
  callSendAPI(sender_psid, response);
}
function callSendAPI(sender_psid, response) {
// Construct the message body
let request_body = {
    "recipient": {
        "id": sender_psid
    },
    "message": response
}
// Send the HTTP request to the Messenger Platform
request({
    "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
    "qs": { "access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    "method": "POST",
    "json": request_body
}, (err, res, body) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('message sent!')
    } else {
        console.error("Unable to send message:" + err);
    }
});
}
```

So as you can see, the script will already sending the message to the user on Messenger before the query is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some unneccessary variables and problems in your code (`data = data.response` should probably be `data = response.data`, for example), this would be a modern version with async/await and arrow functions. You do not need a callback function in that case, callSendAPI will be called after the AJAX request. I have also removed the `switch`, because a simple `if` is sufficient:

```
const handlePostback = async (sender_psid, received_postback) => {
    // Get the payload for the postback
    const payload = received_postback.payload;

    // Set the response based on the postback payload
    if (payload === 'yes') {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://api.irail.be/connections/?from=Mechelen&to=Puurs&date=010219&time=1650&timesel=departure&format=json&lang=en&fast=false&typeOfTransport=trains&alerts=false&resul1=1');
            callSendAPI(sender_psid, {
                'text': response.data.connections.arrival.name
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
};
```

Side note: I would not use 2 different ways to do http requests, assuming you are using superagent too? Because `http.request` would be a possibility with Node.js, but `request` looks like superagent ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put `callSendAPI()` in your Axios callback

```
function handlePostback(sender_psid, received_postback) {

let response;

// Get the payload for the postback
let payload = received_postback.payload;

// Set the response based on the postback payload
switch (payload) {
    case "yes":
        let data = null
        axios.get('http://api.irail.be/connections/?from=Mechelen&to=Puurs&date=010219&time=1650&timesel=departure&format=json&lang=en&fast=false&typeOfTransport=trains&alerts=false&resul1=1')
            .then(function(response) {
                // handle success
                data = data.response;
            })
        response = {
            "text": data.connections.arrival.name
        }
            callSendAPI(sender_psid, response);

        break;
 }
}
```